# LightInject for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, light-inject

has anyone been able to add LightInject to windows phone 8.1 project. I get an error

Could not install package 'LightInject 3.0.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not c
ontain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LightInject NuGet packages has been updated to support Windows Phone 8.1. This will be published to the official NuGet feed as soon as possible.

Best regards 
Bernhard Richter (Author of LightInject)

Comment: Do you know when will that happen?